# Vite cannot find the path when import component, using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

Vite is unable to locate the file that I am trying to import

Vite Output: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbbea.png)

I want to display card components for each item. Firstly, I define the structure of the card display. Then, I create two variables, Product1 and Product2, utilizing this structure. Finally, I export and import these variables into our App.jsx file.

Remark

- All files are stores under src
- Display.jsx, Content.jsx are stored in Components

`Display.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";

export default function Display({ Title, SubTitle, Content, Link }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Card>
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>{Title}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Subtitle>{SubTitle}</Card.Subtitle>
          <Card.Text>{Content}</Card.Text>
          <Card.Link href={Link}>Learn More</Card.Link>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    </>
  )
}
```

`Content.jsx`

```
import Display from "./Component/Display";

export const Product1 = (
  <Display
    Title="Title1"
    SubTitle="Subtitle1"
    Content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor"
    Link="https://example.com/products/sunny"
  />
);

export const Product2 = (
  <Display
    Title="Title2"
    SubTitle="Subtitle2"
    Content="Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis"
    Link="https://example.com/collections/all-tents/products/cloud-creek-ultralight-freestanding-tent"
  />
);
```

`App.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Product1, Product2 } from "./Component/Content";

export default function Apps() {
  return (
    <>
      {Product1}
      {Product2}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please use example.com when you need an example domain. Your post was downvoted because automated tools flagged it as spam due to your *particular* choice of domains.